# selected date from calendarextender is not populated in the asp.net text box

Tags: asp.net

I hvae a textbox and image button.upon clicking image button , the calendarextender will appear and the selected date from calendarextender should be populated in the textbox.but date is not populated.please guide me to fix this issue.

Here is my code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAccidentDate" MaxLength="10" Text=""
     runat="server" SkinID="ClaimTextBox" Width="80px" TabIndex="1" />

<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" 
      TargetControlID="txtAccidentDate" Mask="99/99/9999"
      MessageValidatorTip="false" MaskType="Date"
      DisplayMoney="Left" AcceptNegative="Left"
      ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
     runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAccidentDate" 
     Display="None" 
     ErrorMessage="Please select Accident Date" 
      ValidationGroup="Insured" SetFocusOnError="true">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
     runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAccidentDate"
     ValidationGroup="Insured" Display="None"
     ErrorMessage="Please Enter valid Date" 
     SetFocusOnError="true"
     ValidationExpression="(((0?[1-9]|1[012])[/.](0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])[/.](29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)[/.](19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2[/.]29[/.]((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender5" 
     runat="server" Enabled="True"
     TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator2">
</cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>

<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender6"
     runat="server" Enabled="True" 
     TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator1">
</cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>

<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" 
     runat="server" Enabled="True"
     PopupButtonID="imgcal" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
     TargetControlID="txtAccidentDate" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgcal" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
     ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" /> 

<span class="helpInformantion">(mm/dd/yyyy)</span>
```

Comment: Could you please try without MaskedEditExtender control on the textbox. I remember some time I ago I faced similar issue where a MaskedEditExtender control conflicting with CalendarExtender.

Comment: Check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463258/using-a-calendarextender-with-a-maskededitextender

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used ScriptManager right. Just use **ToolScriptManager** Instead of **ScriptManager**

i.e.,

Change This

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

to

```
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Try this code

```
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccidentDate" MaxLength="10" Text="" runat="server" SkinID="ClaimTextBox" Width="80px" TabIndex="1" />

        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAccidentDate" 
            Mask="99/99/9999" MessageValidatorTip="false" MaskType="Date" DisplayMoney="Left" AcceptNegative="Left" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />

      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAccidentDate"
            Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please select  Accident Date" ValidationGroup="Insured"
            SetFocusOnError="true">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAccidentDate"
            ValidationGroup="Insured" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please Enter valid Date"
            SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="(((0?[1-9]|1[012])[/.](0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])[/.](29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)[/.](19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2[/.]29[/.]((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender5" runat="server" Enabled="True"
            TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator1">
                                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender6" runat="server" Enabled="True"
            TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator1">
                                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" Enabled="True" PopupButtonID="imgcal"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtAccidentDate" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgcal" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" />
        <span class="helpInformantion">(mm/dd/yyyy)</span>
```

Comment: @senthilstayss Copy my above code and try this instead of your code

Comment: I have tried your code also.it says ToolScript manager is not a known element.But when i add <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">              </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>  .It doesn't show any warning but not working.did i miss aything to install ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which version of Ajax ToolKir are you using?

Comment: ajax control tool kit 3.0.30512.0

Comment: Please use the Latest version of Ajax Tool kit... Link here https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091

Comment: I tried to install the latest version.I have vs 2010 installed on my system.  got the following error. Error 99 (0): error CS1705: Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' uses 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: @senthilstayss Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219832/error-cs1705-which-has-a-higher-version-than-referenced-assembly

Comment: <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly><dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </assemblyBinding> This is how only my web.config looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code to set the of selected calender date to text box.
you can do this by writing code on calender's **SelectionChanged** Event

Your code should look like

```
 protected void calendarextender_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   txtAccidentDate.text = calendarextender.SelectedDate;
 }
```

Here calender extender is the id of your extender.

Comment: Man..that is extender event. there is no SelectionChanged event for that

Comment: oh sorry, i misunderstood.